# I am trying to add Twilio broadcast SMS feature to my Django app, but can't work out how to retrieve all Database phone numbers

Tags: python, django, api, twilio

I have created a 'Post' model in my Django app that uploads a basic article to the database. I am trying to implement a feature that notifies users that a new article has been uploaded via SMS, but this needs to be sent to all users who have registered their number in the database (saved in a separate 'Profile' model).

I have added a 'save' function to the model that sends the SMS when the post is uploaded:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    detail_text = models.TextField(default='')

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    account_sid = settings.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID 
    auth_token = settings.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN 
    user_numbers = ''

    client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

    message = client.messages.create(
                                  body= 'Hello, a new article is available from your 
                                  dashboard.',
                                  from_= settings.TWILIO_NUMBER,
                                  to = user_numbers         
    )

    print(message.sid)

    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I have made the API work with a single number, hard-coded in the app, but now want to draw numbers from the database and send them to all users who have registered their mobile number.

I have tried using Profile.objects.get(phone_numbers) but this didn't work. Looking at the Twilio docs I am minded that I will need to save the numbers in settings.py as an array and change the code in the 'save' function to run a for loop that iterates through all numbers in the array and assigning this to the 'user_numbers' variable using settings.USER_NUMBERS (for example). I, however, am quite new to Python and Django and do not know how to do this.

Twilio's example:

```
def broadcast_sms(request):
    message_to_broadcast = ("Have you played the incredible TwilioQuest "
                                                "yet? Grab it here: https://www.twilio.com/quest")
    client = Client(settings.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, settings.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN)
    for recipient in settings.SMS_BROADCAST_TO_NUMBERS:
        if recipient:
            client.messages.create(to=recipient,
                                   from_=settings.TWILIO_NUMBER,
                                   body=message_to_broadcast)
    return HttpResponse("messages sent!", 200)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Some relevant docs that I've read through include:

[Twillio - Broadcast SMS Text Messages from Python](https://www.twilio.com/blog/broadcast-sms-text-messages-python-3-django)

[One API Call to send message to multiple people](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181548-Can-I-set-up-one-API-call-to-send-messages-to-a-list-of-people-)

Comment: Not sure about the Twilio part. But just a heads up overriding the save() method on the model will cause that logic to happen when the post is edited not just during the initial creation. There is a way around this by checking if self._state.adding is True in the save() method before running your logic (which means it's the initial save).

Comment: Wasn’t aware and that’s really good to know. I’ve amended this part of the code. Many thanks.

Comment: @wjh18 or `if not self.pk`, if it feels too dirty to peek into an underscore-prefixed member.

Comment: @AKX It's not a private instance variable, it's named that way to avoid field name conflicts. And it's used in the official Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/). `if not self.pk` won't work in certain situations like if you have a UUID as the primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not provide your models, so i will assume that you have a Profile model with a phone_number field.
Use this save method inside your Post class:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk: # Only if the instance is being created the code is executed
        phone_numbers = [profile.phone_number for profile in Profile.objects.all()]

        account_sid = settings.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID 
        auth_token = settings.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
        client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
    
        for phone_number in phone_numbers:
            if phone_number:
                message = client.messages.create(body='Hello, a new article is available from your dashboard.', from=settings.TWILIO_NUMBER, to=phone_number)

    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Apologies, but your assumption was correct, the Profile model contains a phone_number CharField. I amended the save function with the above code and am happy to say it absolutely worked. I had previously adapted the code and managed to assign a phone_numbers list to 'to', but the Twilio API would only send this to the first number in the list. The code above fixed this - many thanks!